# Very Simple Smooth Animation with GTK+2 and Cairo

Tags: c, animation, gtk, cairo, gtk2

I'm using gtk+2.0 and cairo. I wrote a simple program that open a window and 
move a point. A simple biliard, only horizontal motion. It's just a test.

The problem is that it seems to be not so smooth, and I would ask if there 
are some gtk or cairo expert here that could check for errors in the code.

Thanks.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>

gboolean timeout(gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *widget = GTK_WIDGET(data);
    if (!widget->window) return TRUE;
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
}

gboolean configure(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventConfigure *event, gpointer data)
{ 
    return TRUE;
}

double px = 10;
double vx = **2**;

gboolean expose(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
    cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, event->area.x, event->area.y, event->area.width, event->area.height);
    cairo_clip(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr,1,0,0);
    cairo_arc(cr, px, 100, 6, 0, 2*M_PI);
    cairo_fill(cr);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr,0,0,0);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

    if (px <= 3 || px >= 200-3) vx = -vx;
    px += vx;
    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *title = "Test";
    int sx = 200;
    int sy = 200;

    gtk_init(NULL,NULL);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),title);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER (window), 2);

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),&window);
    GtkWidget *drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    //g_signal_connect(window,"key-press-event",G_CALLBACK(on_key_press),NULL);

    const GdkColor bianco = { 0, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0xffff };
    const GdkColor nero = { 0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };
    gtk_widget_modify_bg(drawing_area, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &bianco);

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(drawing_area, sx, sy);

    g_signal_connect(drawing_area,"configure_event",G_CALLBACK(configure), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(drawing_area,"expose_event",G_CALLBACK(expose),NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), drawing_area);
    gtk_widget_show(drawing_area);

    g_timeout_add(**10**, timeout, window);

    if (!GTK_WIDGET_VISIBLE (window))
        gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    else {
        gtk_widget_destroy (window);
        window = NULL;
    }

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add a cairo context and rendering in it..and then do a copy operation at the end of the expose event in the drawing widget?

Comment: You may need to call `cairo_flush()`; and why create and destroy on every expose? It seems better to create at startup and destroy on exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so smooth ? Well, with a period of 100ms, you're drawing at best 10 frames per second, no wonder it's not smooth... You should aim for 60 fps. Furthermore, you're invalidating the whole widget by calling gtk_widget_queue_draw, so your call to cairo_clip is mostly useless, as the clipping region is the whole widget. You should call gtk_widget_queue_draw_area instead so your clipping region is useful, and determining the area by keeping a record of the animation at frame *n* and *n-1*, so you redraw both areas to avoid the previous frame not being deleted.

There are lots of interesting stuff on animation perception on Owen Tailor's blog, starting with this post and more recent:

http://blog.fishsoup.net/2009/05/28/frames-not-idles/

Give a look at all the posts with figures, it's a gold mine.